# Requiring an image in a functional component - Nuxt/Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My functional component:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  functional: true,
  render(createElement, { props, slots }) {
    const postIcon = createElement('img', {
      class: {
        'i-list__img': true,
      },
      attrs: {
        alt: 'icon',
        src: require(slots().postIcon[0].text.trim()),
      },
    })
    // rest of the code is hidden
  }
})
```

I'm using this component:

```
<ListMenu>
  <template #postIcon>
    ~/assets/images/chevron-right.svg
  </template>
</ListMenu>
```

But Nuxt cannot find this image (though it is there): `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '~/assets/images/chevron-right.svg'"`

I just want to process this image through webpack, just as in a .vue SFC template.

**UPDATE 1**

if i hardcode url:

```
src: require('~/assets/images/image.svg')
```

It does work, but if i use:

```
src: require(slots().postIcon[0].text.trim())
```

It doesn't. I just checked a type of slot and its `string`, what's wrong?

**SOLUTION**

```
src: require(`~/assets/images/${slots().postIcon[0].text.trim()}`)
```

This way it does work, but why it didn't when i used whole path in a slot before?

Comment: From https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports: 
If the URL starts with ~, anything after it is interpreted as a module request. This means you can even reference assets inside node modules

Comment: But for nuxt it's different: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/